# java TitledBorder with empty title has a slightly larger border

Tags: java, swing, border, titled-border

I create borders for JPanels using the following code

```
TitledBorder border = BorderFactory.createTitledBorder(
      BorderFactory.createEtchedBorder(EtchedBorder.RAISED),
      title,
      TitledBorder.LEFT,
      TitledBorder.TOP);
border.setTitleFont(font);
border.setTitleColor(color);
panel.setBorder(border);
```

When `title` is the empty string, the border is closed, which is exactly what I want.
However, the border is also slightly larger than normal.
[image]
How can I fix this?

Only using

```
TitledBorder border = BorderFactory.createEtchedBorder(EtchedBorder.RAISED);
```

yields the same result.

Comment: *How can I fix this?* modify the code from the TitleBorder class. Or use a LineBorder. Post a proper [mre] if you need more help.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to have an empty border, try
[BorderFactory#createEmptyBorder](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/BorderFactory.html#createEmptyBorder())

I hope, that can help you.
Greetings, MausTipTop100!

Comment: I want the border to be drawn, just with the same width and height as the borders with title.